# How do I get jQuery to work in my Typescript files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I don't understand why my jQuery doesn't work in my Typescript files.
I don't get any errors. It's just non-responsive. When I click on the div with the class="test" nothing happens and the console.log in the app.component.ts does not print to the console. I'm stumped.

The following is my folder structure. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
    --app
    ----app.component.ts
    ----main.ts
    --node_modules
    --typings
    --index.html
    --jquery.d.ts
    --package.json
    --tsconfig.json
    --typings.json
```

The following is my main.ts

```
    import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
    import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

    bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The following is my app.component.ts

```
    /// <reference path="../jquery.d.ts" />
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    declare var $: Function;

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
                 <div class="test">TEST</div>`
    })
    export class AppComponent {}

    $('.test').click(function(){
    $('.test').hide();
    console.log('testing');
    });
```

The following is my index.html file

```
     <html>
       <head>
         <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

         <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
         <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
         <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js">  </script>
         <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

         <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
         <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
         <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
         <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

         <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
         <script>
           System.config({
             packages: {
             app: {
             format: 'register',
             defaultExtension: 'js'
             }
           }
         });
         System.import('app/main')
           .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
         </script>
        </head>

        <!-- 3. Display the application -->
        <body>
          <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        </body>
       </html>
```

The following is my tsconfig.json

```
  {  
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "system",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "removeComments": false,
   "noImplicitAny": false
  },
   "exclude": [
   "node_modules",
   "typings/main",
   "typings/main.d.ts"
   ]
  }
```

The following is my typings.json

```
{
 "ambientDependencies": {
 "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
 "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438"
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it "doesn't work"?  Are you getting any error messages? What's the expected behavior that you're not seeing?

Comment: I don't get any errors. It's just non-responsive.  When I click on the div with the class="test" nothing happens and the console.log in the app.component.ts does not print to the console. I'm stumped.

Comment: @ChadKerr , any console errors?

Comment: Satej S,  No. There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.test')` use `JQuery.Of('.test')`

Comment: Thank you. Now I receive an error, Property 'Of' does not exist on type 'function'. Do I need to declare it like so.  "declare var JQuery: Function;"

Comment: Isn't it jQuery (case sensitive)?

Comment: @AndreasL. I changed JQuery to jQuery and still get no response. Thanks though.